# how to show or convert the current time as local time from server time

Tags: mysql

if i have the server in us for my web based project,the date and time functions shows the current time based on the server,but i want my local time i.e,IST ,how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Get your server's time in UTC, then convert to local time on the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var server_time_utc = Date.UTC(2011,1,6,4,30);
    var d = new Date(server_time_utc + new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
    alert(d);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in your queries. But you need to know the timezone of client (in your case IST) and the server in your case -- one of the US timezones.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(`my_timestamp_field`,'US/Eastern','US/Central');
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
Select convert_tz(now(),'EST','IST') ;
```

Please refer, for more info,

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Answer (score 0):

If you are dumping data to your local machine, put the field type as timestamp. TIMESTAMP makes dates to be shown in local mysql server's time zone:

[TIMESTAMP values are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and converted back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html)

In general my suggestion is to set server time zone to GMT (specially if date field types are not TIMESTAMP) to avoid confusion between developers/over time.